# #include library for array syntax in C?

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio

I am getting a strange compilation error when using MS Visual Studio: I get errors due (apparently) to my use of array indexing. I've reduced my code down to simply:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  void main(void) {
      int x[10];
      for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
          x[i] = 0;
      }
      return;
  }
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
```

I've never had this issue before, and am flummoxed--I figure I must be missing something obvious. Is there a specific header that needs to be included for array syntaxing to work? I thought this was a built-in feature of C?

Comment: `int i, x[10]; for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {`

Comment: in `c-language` you need to declare all variable's before use. What do you mean by `void main(void)` along with `return;`

Comment: @JosEdu declaring main as a function that returns nothing and takes no arguments, that's valid C89

Comment: @OregonTrail: Not exactly. An implementation is permitted to accept `void main(void)`, but all hosted implementations *must* accept `int main(void)`. There is no good reason to use `void main(void)`.

Comment: @DOOM: That's true for C prior to the 1999 ISO C standard. Microsoft's C compiler notoriously does not implement C99. And the relevant feature here is not mixing declarations and statements; it's declaring a variable in a `for` loop header (two distinct features, both supported in C++ and in C99, neither supported in C90 or by Microsoft's C compiler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio uses the older C syntax, you need to predeclare all variables

```
void main(void) {
      int i;
      int x[10];
      for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
          x[i] = 0;
      }
      return;
  }
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to pre-declare in C anyway, unless you're using C11.

Comment: Huh, strange, the code that I inherited and am working from uses this syntax   for (int i=0; ...) all over-- perhaps VS is compiling into C++?

Comment: If you want your C code to be portable, definitely.

Comment: @user1004061  yes, various C compilers use a newer C standard where that syntax is supported.  However the microsoft compilers, while supporting some of the latest C++ standards, haven't changed their C support for a long time.  Which, on the positive side, means any code you do write is likely to be more compatible with all kinds of C compilers.  Especially in the embedded world

Comment: It's strange, because the other code compiles into Visual Studio as well. Anyway, sounds like I was making a stupid error-- thanks for your help.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The ability to mix declarations and statements, as well as the ability to define variables in `for` loop headers, was added in C99, not C11.

Comment: @user1004061, if the file extension of the other one is .cpp it will use the c++ compiler, which will compile a lot of C code no problem, and in C++ its legit syntax

Comment: @user1004061: No, VS doesn't compile C code *into* C++.  It compiles either C code or C++ code, depending on how you invoke it and on the extension (`.c` vs. `.cpp`) on the source file name. When it's compiling C++, it accepts mixed declarations and statements, as well as variable declarations in `for` loop headers, because those have been in standard C++ for a very long time. They've only been in standard C since 1999; yes, that's also a long time, but Microsoft is not particularly interested in implementing C past the 1990 standard.

Comment: Ah, the file extension is what makes the difference. The other files that I inherited had .cpp extensions. Since the code did not contain any class definitions, I assumed they were in pure C (just with a C++ extension), but apparently they were taking advantage of non-class features in C++. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @user1004061: They may or may not have been using non-class features of C++. C++ is *nearly* a superset of C; it's not difficult to write code that's valid, and has the same meaning, in both languages. (It's also not difficult to write valid C code that's invalid C++, or that's valid C++ with different semantics.)